# Is it possible to use only a piece of the image in a full background?

Tags: html, css, background

I have an image:

[image: use only a piece]

I want to use it on the background of a `div` with `width: 100%` and set `repeat-x`. But I want to use only the black part, I don't want to use other images, I want to fix the image on a small piece.

Is it possible?

Comment: Note: Placing the image bellow doesn't "work". What if I need to `repeat-y` or both?

Comment: Try CSS Sprite... I am not sure if it works for background as well. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is somewhat like CSS sprites, I guess.

An article I used myself to learn about them is: [CSS Sprites: What they are, why they're cool, and how to use them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

--[Edit]--

An example of repeating backgrounds (this one's in the y-direction): [Vertical repeating background with CSS sprites](http://www.phpied.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/sp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is definitely not possible.

There is the `clip` property but that works only on elements, not backgrounds.

You will have to use an image that is clipped to your needs.